# How to Calculate last Friday of previous month from current month in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to calculate the last Thursday of previous month from current month

```
set @ldom = dayofweek(last_day(curdate()));

select     
case
    when @ldom = 7 then last_day(curdate()) - interval 1 day
    when @ldom = 6 then last_day(curdate())
    when @ldom = 5 then last_day(curdate()) - interval 6 day 
    when @ldom = 4 then last_day(curdate()) - interval 5 day 
    when @ldom = 3 then last_day(curdate()) - interval 4 day
    when @ldom = 2 then last_day(curdate()) - interval 3 day
    else last_day(curdate()) - interval 6 day
end as last_friday
```

It gives me the last friday of current month but i need to calculate the last friday of previous month

Comment: So is it Thursday or Friday?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is confusing. At the top you have written you need to get last Thursday. At the bottom, you want to get last friday of last month. Please change your question.

Comment: Which database are you using .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the last thursday, then try this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/16634

```
SELECT case weekday(last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month)) 
when 6 then date_sub(last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month),interval 3 day)
when 5 then date_sub(last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month),interval 2 day)
when 4 then date_sub(last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month),interval 1 day)
when 3 then date_sub(last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month),interval 0 day)
when 2 then date_sub(last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month),interval 4 day)
when 1 then date_sub(last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month),interval 5 day)
when 0 then date_sub(last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month),interval 6 day) end day
```

Comment: THANK U SENDING ME THE REPLY BUT SIR I HAVE ONE PROBLEM I HAVE ONE TABLE WHICH CONTAINS ID,PRICE AND DATE.I NEED TO CALCULATE THE PRICE OF LAST THURSAY OF PERIOUS MONTH.. IF ON LAST THURSDAY NO ENTRY ID THERE THEN IT SHOULD GO TILL HE FIND THE NEXT DATE...